# Cannot create new GSuite accounts w/ Alias as of 2021-11

Tags: c#, google-directory-api

I'm trying to create users in Google directory using the Google Directory APIs, specifically Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1. If I add a user *with* an alias, it will fail with an error of "If-Match - Error with format of alias" but if I create the user first and then add the alias afterwards, it succeeds.

The really strange thing is that this used to work. Starting somewhere around November 2021, code that I've had working for a few years stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend keeping user and alias creation as two separate API calls. That way if one fails you know whether it's the user create and primary address that's the problem or the alias address which is a problem.

Having said that, can you show your full API call including the POST url and body?

Comment: That's what I was planning to do to fix it, I was hoping someone knew what had changed and if it was intentional, the reason behind the change.

Comment: Right, creating user and alias *should* work with one API call even though I recommend using two. If you want to pursue one API call further then post the exact details of your API call (URI, POST body, etc)

Answer (score 0):

big shot in the dark, seems they increased their sensitivity and added more limiting on their servers "Cloud IoT Core automatically limits projects that generate excessive load"

Especially if this script used to work fine, try using a backoff script.

https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/exponential-backoff

if not, I tried ^^